# How to display the contents inside a div using flexbox

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, flexbox, css-position

I'm having trouble in positioning my items/card using flexbox in my first react app.

I put a div in my card (See the Card component) and I put a display: flex; there but it seems that every card in my output is like a block (column like) and it flex only my content, not the every divs of my card, and what I want is my div to be a row.

I try also flex-direction, but nothing happens, Any idea on how to make that guys?

```
//My code in my Main//

const data = [
  {id: 1, t: 'Card-1',  description: 'This is a Card-1'},
  {id: 2, t: 'Card-2', description: 'This is a Card-2'},
  {id: 3, t: 'Card-3', description: 'This is a Card-3'},
  {id: 4, t: 'Card-4', description: 'This is a Card-4'},
  {id: 5, t: 'Card-5', description: 'This is a Card-5'},
]

function Main () {
return (
<div>
<div className="main-container">

          {data.map(d => {
          return (
              <Card 
                key = {d.id}
                title = {d.t}
                description = 
{d.description}
              />
              )
          })}
          </div>  

</div>)

export default Main;


//end of my Main//

// My code in my Card //

import React from 'react';
import './style.css';

function Card ({ title, description }) {
  return (
  <div className="items">

      <h2>{title}</h2>
        <p>{description}</p>

  </div>
)
}

export default Card;
//

//The style.css of my Card //

div.items {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid darkgreen;
  margin: 15px;
  max-width: 250px;
  min-height: 200px;
  background-color: deeppink;
  flex-direction: column;
}

div.items h2 {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

div.items p {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

//ends here
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: ...but if you don't want a column, remove `flex-direction: column;`

Comment: if you want to have cards next to each other you need display flex on the "row"-element (the container)

Comment: Im sorry I didnt know it im new here on stack overflow. I put all my code there cuz I think that was all necessary. Thanks for your tip!

Comment: Theyre not next to each other when I try display:flex.

Answer (score 1):

I did just put a flex display in main container:

```
.main-container{
  display: flex
}
.div-1 {
  flex: 1 //depends on your taste
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want all the cards display in a row, and the content inside the card has to be the only thing displayed in a column, am I wrong?
If it's only that:

```
.main-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: I try this but theyre in a column type. I want them to be next to each other. I try flex direction:column but its still the same.

Comment: can you do https://jsfiddle.net/ ? at least we can help you and see what you're doing wrong

Comment: I mean I want my card to be like photo gallery type. Sitting next to each other. I try your code but unfortunately it displays column sir.

Comment: LOL you didn't answer my main question : can you do a jsfiddle ? At least we can help you if you show us that portion of the code

Comment: My mistake. Ok I'll try it. Havent heard of jsfiddle but I'll see it so I can show you sir.

Comment: Ive figured it out sir. I just used grid instead of flexbox. Btw, thanks for sharing your ideas sir!